# Change nested views through ng-click in ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to insert views inside view. But it is working only at the defined state but when I trying to change the view with the help of ngClick the state lost the path.

It is like

**View 1** 
   --Sub View 1.1 
  ------Sub Sub View 1.2

But only one sub view will appear that too based on click.

Code is here

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('login',{
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'

        })
        .state('home',{


            url:'/home',
            views:{
                '':{templateUrl:'partials/home.html'},

                'grid@home':{templateUrl:'partials/home-grid.html'},

                'list@home':{templateUrl:'partials/home-list.html'},

                },
                controller: 'homeController'


            })
    })
```

And my Controller

```
    .controller('homeController', function($rootScope, $scope, $location){
        $rootScope.bodyClass = "backround-img1"


        $scope.gridClick = function(){

            $scope.Tview = 'grid@home'

        }
        $scope.listClick = function(){

            $scope.Tview = 'list@home'

        }

    })  ;
```

and in my Main View i have declared the model as below:

```
<a ng-Click="gridClick()">Grid</a>
<a ng-Click="listClick()">List</a>

----------------------------------------

     <div ui-view="{{Tview}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting you with

```
$state.go('stateName');
```

You can use something like this in your controller

```
$scope.changeView=function()
  {
    $state.go('new');
  }
```

The config should be

```
$stateProvider
        .state("home", {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "newView.html",
          controller: "MainCtrl",
        })
        .state("new", {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "someOtherView.html",
          controller: "MainCtrl",
        });
```

Here is the [LIVE](https://plnkr.co/edit/0EWL2E?p=preview) for your code

Comment: Thanks but this not i am actaully looking for, Becuase each view is itself a layout for its sub view, so in your code the newView & someOtherView is just a two different views on the same level, Ideally index.html should inherit the newView and newView inherit someOtherView